# Is there a way for Composer to ignore a branch?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to tell Composer to ignore some branch and not create a release out of it?

Specifically, my project https://packagist.org/packages/michaldudek/foundation has a `gh-pages` branch, but I don't want it showing up on Packagist.org (as its not really a release/library/usable code).

Answer (score 2):

Don't keep `composer.json` on the root of the specified branch. In this case remove the `composer.json` from gh-pages.